# How to properly avoid Thread creation overhead / reuse thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

Let's say I have the following loop that should execute as fast as possible:

```
while(true)
{
    A();
    B();
    C();
}
```

with the following rules:
B() can only start after A() is finished, C() can only start after B() is finished.
B() has high potential to be multithreaded.

If I create new threads within B() to split the work it performs slower compared to the not parallel solution!

I suppose it's the thread creation overhead.
I created a variant where the parallel threads for B() are created outside the while(true) loop.
Every thread has a boolean to signal it finished and every thread has a boolean that is used to signal the thread that it has new work to do.

The threads and C() are waiting for their continuation with the following snippet:

```
while(!boolean)
    Thread.Sleep(1);
```

When the work for B() is very small this is slower than other variants. When B() has it's expected maximum of work it is faster compared to the other variants.

This boolean wait method seems to be very inefficient and stupid...
threadInstance.Resume() is deprecated.

I am pretty sure this is the wrong way anyways.
What is the proper solution for my problem?
I have heard about thread pools and tasks. Is that what I should look into?
I avoided those concepts because I couldn't quickly understand them when reading about them.

Comment: Go and read up on the Threadpool again. Threadpools were made to reuse threads. Actually, .NET keeps one ready at hand for you!

Comment: *I avoided those concepts because I couldn't quickly understand them when reading about them.* "I want a high performance multi threaded application and I want to do it easily and I want it now and I want a pony"

Comment: "I suppose it's thread creation overhead." Profiling is much more reliable than guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks. Read up on tasks.

A task following all the tasks in b followed by C when they are finished.

You try to solve a problem solved some quite long time ago with the Task API (in .NET 4.0 timeframe, i think).

Comment: +1 but reading up on tasks has been tried by the OP *I avoided those concepts because I couldn't quickly understand them when reading about them.*

Comment: Learning isn't fun unless you have a clear benefit and goal in front of you (;

Comment: @Traubenfuchs Yeah, but as you can see there are benefits. In fact, Tasks were done for hundreds of thousand of small operations - so they are extremely optimized ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @TomTom says, Task API is the correct choice for that.

[Task API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was introduced in .NET 4.0 and improved in .NET 4.5. For previous .NET versions [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be the correct approach.